# Cron job fails accessing url with admin_required decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, flask, cron

According to the documentation Cron jobs should be allowed to access admin protected views.  However I get a 302 error if I have the `@admin_required` decorator on the GET method.

In **app.yaml** I have defined this:

```
- url: /generator
  script: run.news.app
  login: admin
```

**the view:**

```
class GeneratorView(MethodView):
    @admin_required
    def get(self):
        return 'success', 200
```

**urls.py**

```
app.add_url_rule('/generator', 'generator', view_func=GeneratorView.as_view('generator'))
```

**cron job:**

```
cron:
- description: Scrape every 3 hours
  url: /generator
  schedule: every 3 hours synchronized
```

**decorator:**

```
def admin_required(func):
    """Requires App Engine admin credentials"""

    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if users.get_current_user():
            if not users.is_current_user_admin():
                abort(401)  # Unauthorized
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))

    return decorated_view
```

the funny part is, when I remove the `admin_required` decorator, the url is still admin-only protected because of `login: admin` in app.yaml.

However my unit test fails the authorization check because of the missing decorator.

```
def test_generator_fails_as_normal_user(self):
        self.setCurrentUser(u'john@example.com', u'123')
        rv = self.client.get('/generator')
        self.assertEqual(rv.status_code, 401)
```

> AssertionError: 200 != 401

If I put the decorator back in, the unit test passes and cron job fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit test's `self.client.get` no doubt doesn't go back all the way to `app.yaml` for routing -- so it's not surprising that, if you remove the app-level check you do in the decorator, it lets non-admin users through.

The real issue however is that the decorator is not finding anybody "logged in" when it's `cron` that's hitting that URL.  This is hinted at (though it surely should be more clearly/explicitly documented!) at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_Securing_URLs_for_cron :

> Note: While cron jobs can use URL paths restricted with `login: admin`,
>   they cannot use URL paths restricted with `login: required`.

This indicates that the serving infrastructure does **not** validate cron requests by checking the currently logged-in user as it would find none.  Rather, it relies on a **header** in the request:

> Requests from the Cron Service will also contain a HTTP header:
>
> `X-AppEngine-Cron: true`
>
> The `X-AppEngine-Cron` header is set internally by Google App Engine. If
>   your request handler finds this header it can trust that the request
>   is a cron request. If the header is present in an external user
>   request to your app, it is stripped, except for requests from logged
>   in administrators of the application, who are allowed to set the
>   header for testing purposes.

So, your decorator must examine the headers at `self.request` -- if it finds `X-AppEngine-Cron: true`, it must let the request through, else it can go on to perform the checks you're doing now.

I'm not quite sure how you should best get at the request's header in your chosen web framework, which you don't mention, but if it was e.g `webapp2` then something like:

```
@wraps(func)
def decorated_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Cron') == 'true':
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # continue here with the other checks you do now
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I am using `flask`. I hope the snippet works there too. I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: `if request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Cron') == 'true':
            return func(*args, **kwargs)`  works in Flask. Many thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

The [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/#decorating-views) seem to say that you can't decorate your methods like that:

> Decorating Views
>
> Since the view class itself is not the view
>   function that is added to the routing system it does not make much
>   sense to decorate the class itself. Instead you either have to
>   decorate the return value of as_view() by hand:
>
> ```
> def user_required(f):
>     """Checks whether user is logged in or raises error 401."""
>     def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
>         if not g.user:
>             abort(401)
>         return f(*args, **kwargs)
>     return decorator
>
> view = user_required(UserAPI.as_view('users'))
> app.add_url_rule('/users/', view_func=view)
> ```
>
> Starting with Flask 0.8 there is also an alternative way where you can
>   specify a list of decorators to apply in the class declaration:
>
> ```
> class UserAPI(MethodView):
>     decorators = [user_required]
> ```
>
> **Due to the implicit self from the caller’s perspective you cannot use
>   regular view decorators on the individual methods of the view however,
>   keep this in mind.**

I don't understand the reasoning, though.